# Rest API pagination with continuationToken ( Azure )

Tags: azure, powerbi, pagination

I try to get list of the builds data from my project
[https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=7.1-preview.7](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/build/builds?api-version=7.1-preview.7)

I only get count - 1000.
I understand that I need to use continuationToken,
but I don't understand where I can find this continuationToken for getting next 1000 lines.

Could you give me some advice or example how I can find out continuationToken?

I'm using Power Bi query.
I created a web connection and realized that I only have 1000 rows.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Comment: This might help https://gorilla.bi/power-query/list-generate-api-calls/

Comment: Note, you need to separate the dynamic and non-dynamic parts of the URL. https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2016/08/16/using-the-relativepath-and-query-options-with-web-contents-in-power-query-and-power-bi-m-code/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The continuationToken is found in the response header as `X-MS-ContinuationToken`. You cannot get the response header in PowerQuery natively, you can via Python or even using a Custom Connector. The continuationToken is simply a number to which item to start for the next call. So you could try adding `&continuationToken=1001` to your call to get the next page. Then again with 2001 etc... till you get no more results.

Suggestion: Have a look at an ODATA approach with Azure DevOps vs API. Here is a good place to start [Azure DevOps Build and Test Reports using OData and REST in PowerBI](https://colinsalmcorner.com/azure-devops-build-and-test-reports-using-odata-and-rest-in-powerbi/)